# JOOQ how can I specify Character Set and Collation

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I need to do the the following sql operation with Jooq:

```
cast(`zip` as CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

but I am always getting `` cast(`zip` as char) ``

I am using the class JooqBaseConverter but I did not figure out yet how to specify characterset and collation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COLLATE` clause (and relevant specialisations for data types) is not yet supported out of the box by jOOQ. The feature request for this is [#2908](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2908).

In the meantime, you'll need to work around this limitation by using [the plain SQL APIs](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/):

```
DSL.field(
    "cast({0} as CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci", 
    String.class, 
    MY_TABLE.ZIP
);
```

Comment: is there any way to do the same thing in the create temporary table statement?

Comment: @ejoncas: Possibly. Would you mind asking a new question with some details?